# How do I increase my mining yield?

Tags: eve-online

What are my options as far as skills, rigs, and fittings that will increase my mining yield?

Also, I think there are some bonuses based on what ship you fly but I'm not sure because there are so many.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various methods of increasing mining yield, through skills, upgrades and using mining crystals.

**Skills** that increase yield:

- Mining increases yield by 5% per level
- Astrogeology increases yield by 5% per level
- Mining Foreman increases yield by 2% per level for your fleet
- Mining Laser Upgrades allows you to fit Mining Laser Upgrade modules
- Exhumers increases the yield of certain ships
- Mining Barge increases the yield of certain ships

**Implants** that increase yield:

- Hardwiring - Inherent Implants 'Highwall' HX-2 increases yield by 5%
- Mining Foreman Mindlink increases yield by 15% but replaces the effects of the Mining Foreman skill
- Michi's Excavation Augmentor increases yield by 5%

**Ships** that increase yield:

- Coveter and Hulk have increased yield based on the Mining Barge skill
- Hulk, Skiff and Mackinaw have a yield bonus based on the Exhumer skill

**Fittings** that increase yield:

- Mining Laser Upgrade
- Strip Miner
- Modulated Strip Miner
- Mining Drones do not *improve* the yield of any other equipment, but provide an additional source of mining

**Mining Foreman Links** that increase yield:

- Mining Foreman Link - Laser Optimisation

In addition to the above, when you're using Modulated Strip Miners you can utilise mining crystals which will increase your mining yield while mining specific types of ore. There is one crystal per asteroid type.

Answer (score 2):

The only ships with significant mining bonuses are [Mining Barges](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ships:Mining_Barges:Mining_Barges:ORE) and [Exhumers](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ships:Mining_Barges:Exhumers:ORE)
Some droneboats have a bonus to mining drones, but that pales into insignificance when compared to the output of a barge.  In terms of skills, obviously [Mining Barge](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mining_Barge) and/ or [Exhumers](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Exhumers) has an impact, as does [Mining](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mining) and [Astrogeology](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Astrogeology).  In terms of modules, [Modulated Strip Miner II](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Modulated_Strip_Miner_II) with appropriate [mining crystals](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ammunition_&_Charges:Mining_Crystals) will give the highest output, which can also be augmented with [Mining Laser Upgrades](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ship_Equipment:Turrets_&_Bays:Mining_Upgrades).